# How can I trigger commandline tab-completion from a mapping?

Tags: key-bindings

I would like to map `,` to have the same effect as typing `:b <Tab>` in Vim; that is, have the `<Tab>` trigger the commandline completion to show all buffers.

I tried `nnoremap , :b <tab>` but I get `^I` in the commandline, instead of triggering the completion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour; otherwise you'd have the reverse problem: you wouldn't be able to enter a `<Tab>` character in the commandline.

You'll have to use the [`feedkeys()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#feedkeys%28%29) function to do this:

```
:call feedkeys(":b \<Tab>", 'tn')
```

The `t` flag in the second argument does the trick; this tells `feedkey()` to handle keys as if they're typed by the user. See the help page for more information on that.

To map it, use:

```
:nnoremap , :call feedkeys(":b \<Tab>", 'tn')<CR>
```

Comment: that is not completly true. You just have to `:set wildcharm=<tab>` and then `nnoremap , :b <tab>`  should just work.

Comment: Thank you @ChristianBrabandt; I was not aware of that setting. Learning Vim really is like learning to play an instrument: you never stop learning new stuff :-)

Comment: yeah, it's one of the more obscure settings.